# Can I step into a debugger expression in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

IntelliJ allows me to evaluate custom expressions when I'm paused at a breakpoint, which is very useful for figuring out if methods are returning the expected result.

But is it somehow possible to step into an evaluated method call so that I can see why the method is returning an incorrect result?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html @Stefan

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/choosing-a-method-to-step-into.html

Comment: I think `F7` by default will attempt to step into the current line.  Note that it may not work in certain cases, e.g. JNDI calls or for methods where IntelliJ can't conjure up any source code.

Comment: I want to step into a method that's not part of the code.

Comment: @Stefan, it's worth trying to step into. most open source libraries include the source code in the jar. other cases, IntelliJ will attempt to decompile the bytecode.

Comment: The method *call* doesn't exist in the code at all. I want to step into a custom method call (like those I can run through "Evaluate Expression").